# Can't Delete row data grid view & Can't insert data to database MYSQL(ODBC) from textbox VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

This is the code I'm currently having:

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System
Public Class FormInput1
    Dim sCommand As Odbc.OdbcCommand
    Dim sAdapter As Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim sTable As DataTable
Private Sub CmdLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdLoad.Click
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM TblInput1"
        OpenDB()

        sCommand = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sql, con)
        sAdapter = New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(sCommand)
        sBuilder = New Odbc.OdbcCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
        sDs = New DataSet()
        sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "TblInput1")
        sTable = sDs.Tables("TblInput1")
        con.Close()
        DGVInput1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("TblInput1")
        DGVInput1.ReadOnly = True
        CmdSave.Enabled = False
        DGVInput1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdAddEdit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdAddEdit.Click
        DGVInput1.[ReadOnly] = False
        CmdSave.Enabled = True
        CmdAddEdit.Enabled = False
        CmdDelete.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub CmdDelete_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdDelete.Click

        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            DGVInput1.Rows.RemoveAt(DGVInput1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
            sAdapter.Update(sTable)

        End If
    End Sub
```

Can't Delete Row (CmdDelete)

```
    Private Sub CmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CmdSave.Click
        sAdapter.Update(sTable)
        DGVInput1.[ReadOnly] = True
        CmdSave.Enabled = False
        CmdAddEdit.Enabled = True
        CmdDelete.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

I have more problem, I have `TxtPeriode.Text`, `Txtstore.text` and `TxtPartNumber.Text` when I click command Button "Save To Database" can't insert to table "TblInput1".

Answer (score 0):

Removing a row from a `DataGridView` **DOES NOT** delete the underlying `DataRow` in the bound `DataTable` so it cannot affect the database.

When you retrieve the data, bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and bind that to the grid.  To delete the selected record, call `RemoveCurrent` on the `BindingSource` that deletes the underlying `DataRow`, which inherently removes the corresponding row from the grid.  When you call `Update` on the data adapter, the rows with a `RowState` of `Deleted` will delete the corresponding record from the database.

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinneey
Error when Code BindingSource setting :

    <`stocktaking`..`tblinput1`>
    Could not get column information for database object named '`stocktaking`..`tblinput1`'

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  As I can't see what you did, I can only guess what you did wrong.  Just create a `DataTable` in the first place if that's all you're going to use.  Do you create an array for one `String`?  Why create a `DataSet` for one `DataTable` then?